# Why This API data is not rendering to React Page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mern

API for getting all kamForms data

```
router.get('/kam', (req, res) => {
  kamForm
    .find()
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        kamData: result,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: err,
      });
    });
});
```

And this is the API call and rendering part, when I inspect the browser all the data is showing in the console repeatedly. I will attach the ss of the console.

```
const PendingApplication = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          {[data].map((item, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>{item.kcpname}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.totalemp}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.kcpnid}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{item.kcpcontact}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[This is how the data showing in the browser consloe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzB8X.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

First, you are causing an infinite loop in your useEffect hook because there is no dependancy array provided. This will run the effect on each render (which in turn sets the state once axios resolves, causing yet another render, which runs the effect, etc).

Second, you are mapping over an array `[data].map`, where `data` is already an array of results. You should probably mean to write `data.map` instead.

```
const PendingApplication = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setData(response.data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.status}</td>
              <td>{item.species}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit eager-sanderson-bwvj0]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, if I do data.map instead of [data].map it's occurring error like this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Comment: In your screenshot `response.data` is an object. `response.data.kamData` is an array. You might want to do `setData(response.data.kamData)` when axios resolves or in your api only return the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
},[]);
```

```
return (
    <div>
        <Table>
            <TableBody>
                {data && data.map((item, index) => (
                    <TableRow key={index}>
                        <TableCell>{item.kcpname}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{item.totalemp}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{item.kcpnid}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{item.kcpcontact}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </div>
);
```

Use empty Square brackets like this at the end of the UseEffect. Everything will work fine. And also make sure data is not null or undefined before rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it's now working on the console. But in the table, it's still doesn't rendering anything.

Comment: did you use data &&  before using map?

Comment: Yes I did, but still the same.

Comment: use ```data && data.map``` not   data && [data].map

Comment: After using data && data.map its occurring an error "TypeError: data.map is not a function ".

Comment: You can simply write `data?.map((item, index) =>` if data is either `null` or `undefined` it will return `undefined` for this check and the jsx part below will not be executed.

Comment: @stmp_lee Log your data that you get from the API call. If it is *not* iterable i.e. not an array in your case, it will not provide the `.map` function.